# What is the meaning of operator |& in bash?

Tags: bash, operators

in Linux bash I see script using `|&` operator like:

`/opt/program.sh |& tee -a /var/log/program.log`

What is the meaning of |& operator?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [§3.2.3 "Pipelines" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), `|&` is similar to `|`, except that:

> If ‘`|&`’ is used, *command1*’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to *command2*’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

That is — anything that `/opt/program.sh` prints to standard output *or* to standard error will be piped into `tee -a /var/log/program.log`.